# Query MySQL Database with Parameters From Dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with unique email addresses. I want to select all `amount` from amount column from Mysql Database where the Email matches the Email column in the database.

Here is my df

```
       email
0      w@g.com
1      y@g.com
2      z@g.com
3      i@g.com
4      p@g.com
```

Here is my code

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['email'])
    scr_device_numbers = pd.read_sql("SELECT amount from db.table WHERE email = %s LIMIT 5", dbConnection, params=row['email'])
    Calculate the average for each of the email
```

I have to do the calculation for each and for all the unique emails.

Comment: I didn't understand your question what's the problem? What calculation do you want to perform?

Comment: calculate the average

Comment: So you have a list of email and for each email, you want to calculate the average of the amount where the email column is that email?

Comment: yes, actually the its much more complicated, but if i can get help with that. I can take it from there

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
s = pd.Series(['w@g.com', 'z@g.com', 'i@g.com', 'p@g.com'])

def get_query(email):
    query = f'''
    SELECT AVG(amount)
    FROM db.table
    WHERE email = {email}
    '''

    return pd.read_sql_query(query, dbConnection).iloc[0,0]

s.apply(get_query)
```

Comment: great effort, but it does not loop through the series

Comment: Yes. it does. In the apply method, you apply your function to all the values in the series